# How to add a dialog in office.js for excel add ins

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

When a user click a button from taskpane - a new dialog should open in excel itself redirecting to specific link. I tried many time but no results or error are seen. Let me know what files should I edit.

Example:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins.md

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

```
function openDialog() {
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
    'https://localhost:3000/popup.html',
    {height: 45, width: 55},

    function (result) {
      dialog = result.value;
      dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, 
        processMessage);
  }
);
}

function processMessage(arg) {
  document.getElementById("user-name").innerHTML = arg.message;
  dialog.close();
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code that calls the Dialog API.

Comment: Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('url', {height: 30, width: 20});
Do i have to edit anything in manifest file?

Comment: function openDialog() {
  //Call the Office Common API that opens a dialog
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://url", {
    height: 45,
    width: 55
  });
}

Comment: You need to provide more than that. Provide the whole function that calls displayDialogAsync and shows your error handling.

Comment: If it is an external url, you have to add it to <AppDomains> in the manifest IIRC.

Comment: @RickKirkham With the above code am am able to open dialog now. If i change the url the dialog window does not open. What changes should I make in the files to open another url in dialog.

Comment: @Lumpenstein I even added <appDomani> in manifest but it did not helped.

Comment: You don't have any error handling. You can't troubleshoot till you know what the error is. Please read this entire article section: [Dialog API - Handle errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#handle-errors-and-events).